# How do I get a cell to dynamically move and update?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

I have a workbook that has multiple sheets. The content that gets entered into a sheet changes monthly. For instance, sometimes I will have 5 entries, and sometimes I will have 400 enteries in a sheet. In one sheet, the entries are products and their quantity. In another sheet, the entries are products and how many items have sold. I would like to create a function that always appears after the last row and sums the values in a column. In another sheet, I would like to have a formula that subtracts the value of two cells. My issue is that the cells that are referenced will change dynamically depending on how many entries there are. For example, if I write a function for a cell that sums the values in a column, but where that cell is depends on the number of entries, I don’t know how to reference that cell as its position changes. How can I write functions that always appear after the last entry? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Excel Tables in the sheet (select the data, click Insert > Table), and configure the table to show Totals at the bottom of the table. Give the tables meaningful names, e.g. `tblQuantity` and `tblProduct`. Now you can use structured references to subtract total values without referencing a specific row.

```
=tblQuantity[[#Totals],[quantity]]-tblProduct[[#Totals],[sold]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My apologies for not marking it as the answer. Thanks again.